# How to do system call in MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

It is a really old MFC program which I have to use right now. Some calculation needs to be done and I already have a python script written for that, writing things again in c++ is too time consuming, so I made MFC output data in text file, then try to use `system()` to call python (as `system("python XXX.py")`) and write the result back in another text file. But when the MFC program ran to that part, the command window popped up briefly but no text file was generated. I tested `system("python XXX.py")` in a separated c++ project and it worked fine, so it must be a MFC problem, I have googled and tried using `_spawnl()`, but it is not working. Needs help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `HINSTANCE result = ShellExecute(0, 0, "path.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`
If there is error it should give you a good idea what's wrong. Also there is `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcess`

Comment: Are you sure that the directory were you place the Output is correct? Do you use the current directory withinthe phython code? If so take care that the current directory of the calling program is correc. Or use ShellExecuteEx and preset the directory in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an MFC problem. `system()` in both cases is the same C library function.

However, note that `XXX.py` is a filename without path. Your problem might simply be that the file isn't found.

Comment: I already put path before the python script. I realized that I am using Anaconda as my Python environment, so I did this: system("C:\\Anaconda\\python.exe \"C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\ipython-script.py\" path\XXX.py"), and the problem is solved.